# Missing keyword error in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, alter-table

I am trying to alter a column data type in SQL but it gives me missing keyword error. I have looked at how to change a column in several places and they all gave me this piece of query:

I am using this:

```
 ALTER TABLE CARD 
  MODIFY COLUMN Charged NUMBER(4,2);
```

Comment: What statement are you using?

Comment: I guess I should have said query.

Comment: The COLUMN keyword is superfluous: ALTER TABLE Card MODIFY Charged NUMBER(4,2)` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The COLUMN keyword is superfluous — this should work:

```
ALTER TABLE Card MODIFY Charged NUMBER(4,2)
```

Interestingly, standard SQL does not support MODIFY (which I did not know until I went to check the   [SQL Syntax](http://savage.net.au/SQL)).  According to the SQL standard (ISO/IEC 9079-2:2003), you can write:

#### 11.12 `<alter column definition>` (p572)

Change a column and its definition.

```
<alter column definition>    ::=   ALTER [ COLUMN ] <column name> <alter column action>

<alter column action>    ::=
           <set column default clause>
     |     <drop column default clause>
     |     <add column scope clause>
     |     <drop column scope clause>
     |     <alter identity column specification>
```

(and in SQL 2003, `MODIFY` is not an SQL keyword).  In this formulation, the keyword `COLUMN` is permitted but is optional.  It also does not seem to allow changing the type of the column, unlike 'real' DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing brackets and you should omit the word `COLUMN`:

```
ALTER TABLE CARD MODIFY ( Charged NUMBER(4,2));
```

See [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_3001.htm#i2133121) for examples of how to modify columns.

Comment: The brackets (parentheses in American jargon) are optional.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "column" as a keyword:

```
ALTER TABLE card
MODIFY charged NUMBER(4,2);
```